# POSTGRESQL Join on generated string property

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I got a table named `work_schema_items` which contains a couple of columns and the important one for this question is varchar column weekday. The contains the following values:

```
end_time    start_time    weekday
12:00       06:00         Monday
14:30       12:30         Monday
15:00       14:45         Monday
18:00       15:00         Monday
21:00       18:30         Monday
23:00       21:15         Monday
23:59       23:15         Monday
12:00       06:00         Tuesday
14:30       12:30         Tuesday
15:00       14:45         Tuesday
18:00       15:00         Tuesday
21:00       18:30         Tuesday
23:00       21:15         Tuesday
23:59       23:15         Tuesday
12:00       06:00         Wednesday
14:30       12:30         Wednesday
15:00       14:45         Wednesday
18:00       15:00         Wednesday
21:00       18:30         Wednesday
23:00       21:15         Wednesday
23:59       23:15         Wednesday
12:00       06:00         Thursday
14:30       12:30         Thursday
15:00       14:45         Thursday
18:00       15:00         Thursday
21:00       18:30         Thursday
23:00       21:15         Thursday
23:59       23:15         Thursday
12:00       06:00         Friday
14:30       12:30         Friday
15:00       14:45         Friday
18:00       15:00         Friday
21:00       18:30         Friday
23:00       21:15         Friday
23:59       23:15         Friday
```

When I run the following sql query:

```
select 
    t.date,
    t.weekday,
    work_schema_items.weekday
from (
    select
        dd::date as date,
        to_char(dd, 'Day')::varchar as weekday
    from 
        generate_series('2019-12-08'::timestamp, '2019-12-16'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) dd
    ) as t
left join work_schema_items on t.weekday = work_schema_items.weekday
order by date
```

I get this result:

```
2019-12-08  Sunday      NULL
2019-12-09  Monday      NULL
2019-12-10  Tuesday     NULL
2019-12-11  Wednesday   Wednesday
2019-12-11  Wednesday   Wednesday
2019-12-11  Wednesday   Wednesday
2019-12-11  Wednesday   Wednesday
2019-12-11  Wednesday   Wednesday
2019-12-11  Wednesday   Wednesday
2019-12-11  Wednesday   Wednesday
2019-12-12  Thursday    NULL
2019-12-13  Friday      NULL
2019-12-14  Saturday    NULL
2019-12-15  Sunday      NULL
2019-12-16  Monday      NULL
```

What I'm expecting is to get the weekday value for every day just like I do with Wednesday. How come only Wednesday is properly joined? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

`char` is a fixed length datatype and Wednesday is the longest weekday string. It keeps its width even if I did convert it to `varchar` which resulted in that I tried to join `"Monday   "` to `"Monday"`.

A simple TRIM() solves the problem:

```
select 
    t.date,
    t.weekday,
    work_schema_items.weekday
from (
    select
        dd::date as date,
        TRIM(to_char(dd, 'Day')::varchar) as weekday
    from 
        generate_series('2019-12-08'::timestamp, '2019-12-16'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) dd
    ) as t
left join work_schema_items on t.weekday = work_schema_items.weekday
order by date
```